# AbstractMethodError due to Apache Abdera Dependency

Tags: maven, apache-abdera

I am using following Apache Abdera dependency for consuming an Atom feed.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.abdera</groupId>
        <artifactId>abdera-parser</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

After I add abdera dependency into pom.xml, I receive an `AbstractMethodError` from another service. Following is the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.addLocation(StaxUtils.java:1110) [cxf-common-utilities-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:998) [cxf-common-utilities-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:971) [cxf-common-utilities-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.read(StaxUtils.java:898) [cxf-common-utilities-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
```

I am using Java 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked maven transitive dependencies and saw that `xerces` is included by multiple libraries including `Apache Abdera`.

To resolve this error, I updated dependency configuration by excluding `xerces` dependency as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.abdera</groupId>
        <artifactId>abdera-parser</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```